# how to not ignore " 's " in a line of text

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

i have a text file with following contents:

```
the dog's
```

i want to print unique words of this file which should be as following:

```
1 the
1 dog's
```

but this command which i have written, treats " 's " as a new word

```
cat simple2.txt | tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' |sort| uniq -c| sort -nr|head -10
```

the above code which gives me the wrong output as below

```
 1 The
 1 s
 1 dog
```

Comment: What is the point using `'[\n*]'` instead of just `'\n'` ? Works well: `echo "the dog's" | tr -cs '[:alnum:]'\' '\n'`

Comment: What is with the sentence *I said: 'I will never go there!*. Should `I` and `'I` also be considered different words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To consider `'` as part of words, add `'` to the character classes to translate:

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]'\' '\n'
```

And as @Gilles pointed out in a comment, you can replace `[\n*]` with simply `\n`.